# Detect and remove numbers appended to strings with a regex

Tags: php, regex

I receive definitions of words via json. Sometimes I receive stuff like this:

> inclusa1.

(the number can also be 2, 3, and so on). How can I automatically detect (and remove) numeric characters that are appended to words?

Eg: This is acceptable:

> people that live in 1 house.

Eg: This is not acceptable:

> people1.

Comment: Will the dot be always present?

Comment: Maybe match for `[A-Za-z]+[0-9]` and discard.

Comment: the dot can be present, but it is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace('/(?<=[a-zA-Z])[0-9]/', '', $string);`

This just removes any numeric characters preceded by an alpha.

Comment: works almost great. it is removing the numeric character but also the last alpha character of the word where it is being found. Example: inclusa1 becomes inclus. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Instead of using a non-capturing group, you could use a lookbehind (if php supports them). Something like `/(?<=[a-zA-Z])[0-9]/`. Or you could use my approach and a capturing group.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis you're right; I thought the non-capturing group wasn't included at all in the match set, but what I really wanted was a lookbehind. I'll update my answer to match your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a word is just made up of letters, this should work:

```
preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z])[0-9]+/', '$1', $string)
```

Comment: this doesn't work :s Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '['

Comment: Looking at the php docs, I think I needed to surround the expression with `//`. Try that.

Comment: You don't even need to check for whole words, just a single alpha character: `/(?:[a-zA-Z])[0-9]/`

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/(\b[A-Z]+)([0-9]+)/i', '$1', $string);
```